# Show that $\mathscr A_Y$ = $[A \cap Y | A \in \mathscr A]$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $Y$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathscr A)$ be a measurable space and let $Y \subset X$ be a proper, non-trivial subset of $X$.
Show that $\mathscr A_Y$ = $[A \cap Y | A \in \mathscr A]$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $Y$.

This is a question on a past paper for a measure theory exam I'm taking and I'm not quite sure there to start. Should I first prove that $A$ and $Y$ are sigma algebras and then try to prove that $A \cap Y$ is a sigma algebra? Any help would be  appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using the definition of a sigma-algebra? I think that it will follow easily by showing it satisfies the three properties of sigma-algebras.

Comment: @NickyLevering yeah this is what I assumed I had to do but if I'm honest I'm not quite sure how to do that in this case. I have no problem proving something is a sigma-algebra if I'm given subsets of numbers but I don't know how to prove it here.

Comment: I more specifically am finding it difficult to prove the last condition of a sigma-algebra (i.e that the union of all $A_n$ is an element of the sigma algebra in this case. Do I prove that $A_Y$ is an element of $_Y$?

Comment: You know that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and you can use that to prove the final property. For $Y_1,\dots,Y_n \in \mathcal{A}_Y$ you have that you can write $Y_i = A_i \cap Y$. Now $\cup_i Y_i = \cup_i (A_i \cap Y) = Y \cap (\cup_i A_i) \in \mathcal{A}_Y$ because $(\cup_i A_i) \in \mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

1. $Y=X\cap Y$.
2. For any $A\in\mathcal{A}$, $Y\setminus(Y\cap A)=Y\cap(X\setminus A)$
3. For any sequence $\{A_n\}\subset \mathcal{A}$, $Y\cap\bigcup_nA_n=\bigcup_n(Y\cap A_n)$.

The conclusion should follow from this with some minor arguments.